# Get table cell and row knowing the position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used this to access a table specific cell

```
$('table').find('td:eq(' + pos + ')');
```

So, for a 3x3 table,like:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

the positions would equal:

```
012
345
678
```

How can I get the cell positions knowing its position, like knowing `1`, to get `[0][1]`?

Comment: Really confusing... what are you trying to accomplish..?

Comment: input a value that can be from 0 to 8, output, the corresponding cells positions. For 1, you get 0,1.

Comment: for [0][1] try
$('tr:eq(0)').find('td:eq(1)')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just get coords-like output from the number use `%`

```
if (number%cell_count == 0){
    y = number/cell_count -1;
    x = cell_count-1;
} else{
    x = number%cell_count - 1;
    y = Math.floor((number - x )/cell_count);
}
```

And then `$('tr:eq(y) td:eq(x)')`

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dVD9/)

Comment: I think there is a typo, though.

Answer (score 4):

`eq()` uses index. Index works like this for `td-tr` pair.

```
tr  td

0   0 1 2
1   0 1 2
2   0 1 2
```

So, considering `[0][1]`

You need `$('tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)')`.

For co-ordinates :

```
var trIndex = Math.ceil(pos / trCount)
var tdIndex = pos % (tdCount/trCount)

$('tr:eq('+(trIndex-1)+') td:eq('+(tdIndex-1)+')')
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cF85J/)**

Comment: With this I can access the cells positions if I knew them, but all I know is the position of the cell, not the row+line.

Comment: Can you give an example what value you get in `position`.

Comment: In my example, for position=8, I want to get the values 2;2